# How to prevent subprocess.run() (python 3.11) from waiting to close Edge browser to go next command

Tags: python, subprocess, python-webbrowser, python-3.11

Previously, `subprocess.run()` still only opened the Edge browser and executed the next command without closing Edge. Currently, `subprocess.run()` will wait for Edge to close before executing the next statement. How do I make `run()` work like before? I use Python 3.11 and did not make any new settings.

My example code:

```
edge = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
subprocess.run(edge.split())
print('next command')
```

`run()` will wait until I close Edge; when I close Edge, `print` will execute; but previously `run()` would not require me to close Edge.

Additionally, I encounter this problem on Firefox, Chrome, and even when I use `os.system`

Comment: Maybe you have changed the way you was running the python program?

Comment: I use VScode running python 3.11, I'm not sure what settings change happened during the run of my code, but installing it myself did not.

Comment: As an aside, the `split()` there looks really wrong; and those bare backslashes will become a syntax error when you upgrade Python. You always want an `r"..."` string around those pesky Windows paths.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.run()` (and indeed also `os.system()`) always waits for the subprocess to finish, and always has. Something probably changed in Edge, or you are running it differently.

(Vaguely, I recall that running a new browser instance would block, whereas if it was already running, the subprocess would simply launch a new browser window and exit. But I don't remember which browser or which OS I used at the time. I don't use Windows and have never tried Edge. My impression is that Windows processes generally behave somewhat haphazardly when it comes to whether you should expect a new process to just open a window and quit, or stick around until whatever you started has really stopped running. Maybe also experiment with wrapping the process in `cmd /c "start /wait"` vs not.)

If you want a background process, you need `subprocess.Popen()`, with all the additional mundane responsibilities to manage (in particular, at the very least wait for and reap) the subprocesses you create.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538; the question is about Bash subprocesses in particular, but many of the Python details are platform-independent.

Comment: I have also used subprocess.Popen() which seems to work the same as subprocess.run() which waits for Edge to close. I think you are right that the problem comes from changing some browser setting. I'll try searching for general settings for running the browser. Thank you for your useful information.

Comment: No, `subprocess.Popen` only creates the new process, and then continues immediately. If you are seeing something else, it probably means you are doing something more than merely replacing `subprocess.run` with `subprocess.Popen`.